# Export as Runnable Jar file , java executing errors

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, compilation

Working with my project, which is done already, want it to compile and run from a single .jar file, as other mentioned that I should be using Export -> Runnable Jar file.

I select my main Server class, also selecting "Package required libraries into generated JAR" and pressing Finish.

Now I got a file named : Server.jar

Trying to run from console : `java -jar Server.jar` and getting error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at server.Server.main(Server.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

which refers to :

```
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

MANIFEST.MF File (Created auto):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ json-simple.jar mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.ja
 r
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: server.Server
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

I'm tired of guessing the problems, I'm new in Java, first doing the compiling. Any help?

My Server.java class :

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.simple.parser.*;


public class Server {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException{

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        ArrayList<ClientComm> clients = new ArrayList<ClientComm>();

        try{
                new Config();
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Config.getPort()); // can also use static final PORT_NUM , when defined
            System.out.println("Server started");
            System.out.println("test");
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Server error");
        }

        int clientID = 0;

        while(true){
            try{
                    System.out.println("Waiting for new connection");
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                clientID++;
                System.out.println("New connection on socket: " + socket);
                ClientComm clientComm = new ClientComm(socket, clientID);
                clients.add(clientComm);

                if(clientComm.checkAuth() == false) {
                        System.out.println("Client was dropped from connection because auth codes did not match");
                        socket.close();
                }
                else {
                        clientComm.start();
                }  
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Connection Error");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: what are about the lines before connecting to serverSocket?

Comment: @user7294900 editted to see more. :)

Comment: serverSocket can be null, because you previously catch exception and continue

Comment: Doesn't it print an `IOException` details and 'Server error' first?

Comment: Try to set up a remote debugging for your jar and watch what is happenning https://dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat

Comment: @Roman Puchkovskiy it doesnt print anything, just this.

Comment: @AlexeyR. i guess i don't need that kind of debug, because i have everything on my computer aswell. Just wanna know why i get this error, it seems like other external libs are not even touched by .jar file

Comment: @Ervinas34 you do need. Remote does not mean you're deploying app on another computer (however you can to). It just means that you can introduce debugging over already compiled app. Accoring to your log you've got a null pointer exception (not any class loading of deinition stuff) however in your code you're instantiating the object. Thus you can figure out why is it still null and if you're reaching the line.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Okay, ill try :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved long time ago. Was my personal bad with lack of experience in programming with java.